# Python - Find numbers which has not a % at the end using regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I have the following list in Python:
`my_list = ['Prix TTC euros : 10,10', 'Prix HT euros 8,42', 'TVA (20.00%) euros : 1,68']`

I want to get all the numbers like `10,10, 8,42` and `1,68` without the number in percent (20.00%)
My code:

```
my_list = ['Prix TTC euros : 10,10', 'Prix HT euros 8,42', 'TVA (20.00%) euros : 1,68']

for item in my_list:
try:
    found = re.search('([+-]?([0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)', item).group()
except AttributeError:
    found = None  # apply your error handling
print(found)
```

It prints:

```
10,10
8,42
20.00
```

I was trying to escape the last found number 20.00 and get 1,68. Is there any way to escape the number ends with % or something other solution.

Comment: Oh! my bad, numbers can have periods too when in dollars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to avoid matching the percentage values with a word boundary followed with a negative lookahead that will reject matches followed with a `%` symbol:

```
import re

my_list = ['Prix TTC euros : 10,10', 'Prix HT euros 8,42', 'TVA (20.00%) euros : 1,68']

for item in my_list:
    found = re.search(r'[-+]?\b(?!\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?%)\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?', item)
    if found:
        print(found.group())
```

See the [Python demo online](https://ideone.com/vauw1I), output: `['10,10', '8,42', '1,68']`.

See also a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wxFbbQ/1):

- `[-+]?` - an optional `-` or `+`
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!\d+(?:[,.]\d+)?%)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are 1+ digits, an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then 1+ digits immediately to the right of the current location
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?:[.,]\d+)?` - an optional sequence of `.` or `,` and then 1+ digits.

Comment: This works nice but only fails when a white space found right before the ','  like `Prix HT ei: 8 ,42`

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor What is the expected result for `Prix HT ei: 8 ,42`? If you want to match `8 ,42`, use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/wxFbbQ/2).

Comment: Stribizew yes as because I found space in my string sometimes so your suggestion works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with your regex:

```
found = re.search(r'([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)', item).group()
```

this performs as you mentioned. We need to add the `%` in the end of this regex as a negative lookahead

```
found = re.search(r'([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)(?!%)', item).group()
```

That prints:

```
10,10
8,42
20.0  # <---- note the last digit is missing here
```

so to tweak this regex futher we need to exclude the whole number pattern we have matched (ie `([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)`) IF it is ends with the `%`.

Thus we end up with:

```
found = re.search(
    r'([+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)(?!(?:%|(?:[+-]?(?:[0-9]*[,.])?[0-9]+)))',
    item
).group
```

which gives what we want:

```
10,10
8,42
1,68
```

Comment: It fails to get the expected result.

Comment: @SiddiquiNoor I dont think so, unless we are misunderstanding each other. Check it out on regex101 site: https://regex101.com/r/0ufq0q/1/

Comment: yes you are right. This works too. For the second price I got only 8. Later I discovered that there was a space in my second price `8 ,42`.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a negative look-ahead, try using a positive one by ending your expression with `(?=[^0-9,.%]|$)` — “followed by something that’s not `%`, further parts of a number, or by nothing at all”.

Alternatively, just extract all sequences of `[0-9.,%]+` and use Python to throw away bad matches.